# MDCTabBar change font type and size

Tags: ios, swift, material-design, uitabbaritem, material-components

Is it possible to change the font size of tabs into MDCTabBar ?

MDCTabBar is part of a google library to use the design material in iOS

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios

Answer (score -2):

```
CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
UIFont *font = [MDCTypography buttonFont];
if (width <= 320.0) {
    font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Dosis-Medium" size:12];
} else if (width <= 375.0) {
    font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Dosis-Medium" size:14];
} else {
    font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Dosis-Medium" size:15];
}
self.tabBar.unselectedItemTitleFont = font;
self.tabBar.selectedItemTitleFont = font;
```